# why will my JQuery selector not work ?

Tags: jquery

I am a newb to JQuery and am studying out of a book. For some crazy reason this selector /event sdtatement refuses to work even though according to the book it is supposed to work. I know that JQuery is loading as I can get an alert() to work. So can someone tell me what is wrong with this snippet ??

```
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/global.js"></script>

$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

The console says that $ has not been defined. the php statement just refers to  the base url in Codeigniter.

Many thanks

Comment: Use `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` instead of `http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` in the `src` of the first `script` tag.

Comment: Doesn't the console also say that it failed to find the URL of the jQuery library?

Comment: Also, `alert()` is a JavaScript function, so calling it doesn't mean you are using jQuery. jQuery is not the language but a a framework that adds some functionalities to JavaScript in order to facilitate DOM manipulation, ajax requests, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just need to take the `www` out of the URL for the jQuery src.

Answer (score 0):

beside what Guilherme mentioned You need to wrap your selector inside a  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
        alert(1);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put the code like this:

```
<script>
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
    alert(1);
});
</script>
```

Between a script tag